# Why is my personal union ending?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

In *Europa Universalis IV*, I am playing as Aragon, and I have a personal union with Castile. My ruler is called "Alfons VI de Trastámara". Everything is well; Castile's opinion of me is 200, and I have just started to integrate them.

However, now I get a popup saying that my Personal Union ended because "Alfons VI de Trastámara of Castile has died". And I get the restoration of union casus belli. But when I go to my court tab, I can see that King Alfons VI de Trastámara is still alive and well.

So, why did I get a message saying that the king of Castile has died when we're in a personal union? My king is ruling both nations and is still alive. Is this a bug?

I am playing the 1.23 Persia patch with the *Cradle of Civilization* DLC installed.

Comment: Just a sane check. Did you have positive prestige?

Comment: Yes. Turns out their capital was besieged by rebels, and they accepted the demands. The text in the popup just didn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yeah rebel in subjects can be nasty like that. Sorry you lost a PU the hard way.

Comment: Well, technically the rebels kind of executed the previous ruler and installed a new one. It looks like an overlooked corner case in a game script

Comment: @KevinRenskers Can you post your comment as an answer and accept it, so that future readers of this question can see what the answer is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that their capital was besieged by rebels, and Castile accepted their demands, overthrowing me as their king. The text in the popup just didn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I assume it was pretender rebels ? I had the same issue with Naples.